# Spinoza: what would be a concrete example of a thing that "is in" another thing

Tags: ontology, spinoza, substance

Spinoza talks about substance and its modifications.  Since God is the only substance, it follows that everything else that exists is modifications of modifications of modifications ... etc.

As I understand it, when a "thing" A is a modification of a "thing" B, it follows that A is in B.  Only substance, that is God, is in itself.

While abstractly, I can follow the logic, when I try to restate this point with specific things, I am having trouble.

Let me take the human body as an example.  Can we say that the human body is a modification of organs and tissue; organs and tissues are modifications of cells; cells are modifications of cellular structures; cellular structures are modifications of organic chemicals and so on...

Is this what Spinoza would mean of "modification of a modification"?  Or is there another way to view the human body and other concrete things?

I bring this up because it does not make sense to me to say that a "human body" is in "organs and tissue."  Typically, we say "organs and tissues are in the human body".

I am trying to find examples where "thing A" is a modification of "thing B" which can be clearly stated as thing A "is in" thing B.

I am looking for an example where "thing B" is a modification and not God.  It is clear to me what Spinoza means when he says everything is in God.  It is not clear to me how this relates to modifications of modifications.

Comment: "is in" relation here needs comparison of the distance metric to God, not the usual part-whole mereological/subset relation of natural objects. Modification is simply the effect of some definite cause, since by axiom 4 as discussed before, the effect must depend on its definite cause thus the effect exists in and is conceived through something other than itself (ie, its definite cause), and per def 5, this effect is nothing but a modification. And the cause must be effect of another definite cause, so on and so forth, up to the substance only which has true nature of *existence* per prop 7...

Comment: Indeed per Spinoza almost all attributes we perceive and conceive are only modifications (approximations) of God's true attributes which philosophers call empirical, and existentialism (existence is an essence and prior to other essences) only applies to God. So you cannot use usual classic logic, where existence is only a quantifier, to understand Spinoza's God and substance philosophy. So your whole/part body/organ example is not a definite cause/effect relation since a body may miss the said organ and the said organ alone cannot cause a body. Any other efficient causality example is fine...

Comment: Thanks.  So, "is in" is analogous to "has as a definite cause".  Thanks.  That helps.  So, it reflects causality rather than ontology.

Comment: That's correct. In Spinoza philosophy here ontology is the only existent unique substance God, thus his ontology is extreme simple. All confusions must lie in all these modifications, that is, reflected in our epistemology...